# Typescript error-first callback typing (noImplicitAny, strictNullChecks)

Tags: node.js, typescript, interface, callback, typing

I want to declare a function with a *error-first* callback in a project using typscript with `noImplicitAny` and `strictNullChecks`.

Is there a way to declare a `interface` or `type` that allows two different signatures and works when calling?

The simplest and most straightforward way is to declare it as such

```
function example(callback: (err?: Error, result?: {data: any}) => void) {
    callback(undefined, {data: "hello"});
}
```

This, however, allows me to call `callback()` (without paramters) inside `example` which is not something we want to do as the callback should always be called with either an error or a result.

```
function example(callback: (err: Error | undefined, result:  {data: any} | undefined) => void) {
    callback(undefined, {data: "hello"});
}
```

This does not allow `example()`. The callback must be called with 2 parameters.

Both of these patterns however mean that both `err` and `result` can be `undefined`. This is not perfect as the following will cause an error.

```
example((err, result) => {
    if(err) { console.error(err); return; }

    console.log(result.data);
});
```

Since `result` *can* be `undefined`, we can't assume that it has property `data`. To fix this I either have to assert that the second parameter is something when calling, `example((err, result: {data: any}) => void)`, or wrap any interaction with `result` in `if(result)`

---

I want to declare that the callback will **always** be called *either* with
`callback(undefined, { data: "Hello" })` **or** `callback(Error, undefined)`.
Both parameters will never be undefined.

The working way i found to declare this is

```
interface ICallback<r> {
    (err: undefined, result: r): void;
    (err: Error, result: undefined): void;
};

function example(callback: ICallback<{data: any}>) {
    callback(undefined, {data: "hello"});
}
```

This seems to work as, inside `example`, calling `callback(new Error(), {data: "error"})` or `callback(undefined, undefined)` will cause an error.

However; when I'm then using this `example` function;

```
example((err, result) => {
    ...
});
```

Both `err`and `result` are implicitly `any`. Is there any way to declare the callback function that allows for the `(undefined, ISomething)` or `(ISomethingElse, undefined)` signatures which should mean that we can expect parameter2 to be defined if parameter1 is undefined?

Answer (score 1):

> however, allows me to call example(() => void) which is not really something I want as we should handle atleast the error.

This will always be the case. A callback is free to ignore any arguments.

This is because of TypeScript's function compatability : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/type-compatibility.html#number-of-arguments

## More

In a way this is similar to how you are free to ignore catching exceptions. So a callback is free to ignore handling the error if it so wants.

Comment: You are of course correct. I was stating the incorrect problem. I've edited the original question to state the actual problem with `example(callback: (err?: Error, result?: { data: any }) => void) { ...`

Answer (score 1):

The closest I've gotten is:

```
interface NodeCallback<T> {
  (err: any, result?: undefined | null): void;
  (err: undefined | null, result: T): void;
}
```

For a `cb: NodeCallback<string>`, this allows:

- `cb('boom')`,
- `cb(new Error('boom'))`,
- `cb('boom', null)`,
- `cb('boom', undefined)`,
- `cb(null, 'box')`,
- `cb(undefined, 'box')`

but not `cb(new Error('boom'), 'box')`, `cb(null, 123)`, etc.

Unfortunately, it's only good on the consumer side (that is, the one calling the callback) - typescript will give up on contextually inferring parameter types when it hits an overload signature (or, equivalently, an intersection of signatures):

```
// 'err' and 'result' have type 'any', which will error with --strict / --noImplicitAny
const cb: NodeCallback<number> = (err, result) => {};
```

Fortunately there is a [recently opened PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/17819) that may fix this!